# Strange FTP issue

Tags: ftp

With one of our client sites, they switched servers and ever since then we've had a strange issue when uploading.

Basically we normally get this error message :

```
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  File transfer failed
```

And sometimes this one :

```
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  File transfer failed with xxxk uploaded in xxx sec
```

However the file has been uploaded. I've tested it with various ftp clients and they all return this error message.

File permissions are ok. We're running passive FTP and mainly using Filezilla for ftp although I've reproduced the error on Cyberduck and command line too so it seems to be some server setting. But what?

Really annoying as it takes forever to upload major changes as the ftp client keeps reuploading files because it thinks the upload has failed.

Any ideas about what might cause this?

Comment: Ah apologies - will delete and re-post

Comment: No problem. Good luck! :)